# Show that $|uv|^2 = s+t$ when $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=s^2+t^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\text{Show that }|uv|^2 = s+t\text{ when }(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=s^2+t^2.$$
$$\text{ALSO } u = a+bi, v=c+di...(a,b,c,d)\text{ are integers.}$$

So using this somehow I have to show that 17$\times$29 = 493 = s+t

This is what I've got

---

$$|uv|^2 = |u|^2\times |v|^2$$
$$|uv|^2 = |a+bi|^2\times |c+di|^2$$
$$|uv|^2 = (a^2+b^2)\times(c^2+d^2)$$

SO

$$s^2+t^2 = (a^2+b^2)\times(c^2+d^2)$$

SO following on

$$\sqrt{s^2}+\sqrt{t^2} = \sqrt{(a^2+b^2)\times(c^2+d^2)} = \sqrt{|u|^2}\times \sqrt{v|^2}$$
$$s+t= \sqrt{(a^2+b^2)\times(c^2+d^2)} = |u||v|?$$

Am i on the right track here?

Comment: $|a+bi|^2=a^2+b^2.$ There shouldn't be a negative in there.

Comment: Roger @CameronBuie

Comment: From $|uv|^2=s^2+t^2,$ we can only conclude that $|uv|=\sqrt{s^2+t^2}.$ In general, we can't say $$\sqrt{s^2+t^2}\neq\sqrt{s^2}+\sqrt{t^2}.$$ Consider for example $s=3,t=4.$ Now that your question is edited and it's clear what you're supposed to be doing, I recommend you take a look at Dietrich's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=u\overline{u}v\overline{v}=uv\overline{uv}=|uv|^2=(ac-bd)^2+(ad+bc)^2=s^2+t^2$.

Edit: New Question: $493=(4^2+1^2)(5^2+2^2)=(20-2)^2+(8+5)^2=18^2+13^2$.

Comment: Why do we split it into 4 and 1 & 5 and 2? Is it just what ever numbers work or is their a formula to work them out? ANd how do we make them complex numbers? ie $493 = |uv|^2$ where u,v are complex

Comment: and thank you Dietrich Burde

Comment: If you want $17=a^2+b^2$ and $29=c^2+d^2$ with integers, then there is not much choice.

Comment: how did you get from |uv|^2 to (ac-bd)^2+(ad+bc)^2... spent ages trying to work it out and I still can't

Comment: Oh, that is $(a+bi)(c+di)=(ac-bd)+(ab+bc)i$